# fontFamily not picking correct custom font for Arabic locale

Tags: android, android-view, android-fonts

I need to apply custom fonts when the app is in Arabic mode. I am using `style` param in XML to provide the custom font family.

The problem is the custom font is not correctly loaded in Arabic mode; tt is correct when in English mode.

[image]

**Below is my source code:**

**`values/styles.xml`**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_new_style_bold_font" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/gold_under_the_mud_regular</item>
    </style>


    <style name="text_new_style_normal_font" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/gold_under_the_mud_regular</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**`values-ar/styles.xml`**

```
<resources>

    <style name="text_style_bold_font" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arabic_bold_font_family</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_style_normal_font" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/arabic_normal_font_family</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    style="@style/text_new_style_normal_font"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/register_or_login_to_your_account_to_access"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    style="@style/text_new_style_bold_font"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/exclusive_offers_and_deals"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style name must be same into each locales. "text_new_style_bold_font" is not defined into values-ar/styles.xml which must be there. 
So keep both text styles with same name in each styles.xml files. And make sure you are using correct name in layout file.